# How can one find the release date of Microsoft Updates?

Tags: windows

I have a text file with a column like this:

```
KB982665
KB981997
KB981322
KB979687
```

Is there a way (probably with a script in windows or linux) to find the dates each of these updates was published by Microsoft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each KB *should* map to an address of the format `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/XXXXXX`

- KB982665  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982665
- KB981997  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981997

In the source of each page, the `<HEAD>` will contain a meta tag named `Search.DateModified` indicating the date time the article was updated.

`<meta name="Search.DateModified" content="2011-06-10T16&#58;16&#58;00" />`

This decodes (the `&#58;` is a URL encoded `:`) into `2011-06-10T16:16:00`

Comment: This is not true any more. Example: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3182203